# The product of two integer sequences with bounded gaps

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given that two non-negative integer sequences $(a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}} , (b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $a_{i+1}-a_{i}$ and $b_{i+1}-b_{i}$ take only finite values.

define $c_i=min(a_i,b_i)$
Is it true that if $a_{i+1}b_{i+1}-a_{i}b_{i}$ take only finite values then the sequence $c_i$ is bounded.

Comment: This question was asked in term of functions [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168059/if-fn1-fn-leq-2001-gn1-gn-leq-2001-fgn1-fgn-leq)

Comment: Any idea of the origin of this question?